# reusable frame with jquery widget plugin MVC

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, plugins, widget

I need to make a frame or object in mvc vb that can be reusable in all proyect.

fill fields data for search. then  press button 1
this shows a jquery pop up that shows posibles results

when i select the result, the pop up, is closed and fill  the result in the frame, then you can press button 2 for open another pop-up for show person details (this pop-up is another partial view)

the problem is that i need to catch de events of the buttons on the frame, i create a partial view that contains the frame but is not posible to hand the click events, then i think that the better way is to make a jquery widget plugin that controll the click callbacks:

$.widget("mk.Frame", {

```
options: {
    Botones: {
        Limpiar: true,
        Nuevo: true,
        Detalle: true
    }
},

_create: function () {

    var $ob = $(this.element)
    var t = this


    $ob.load('URL_PARTIAL_VIEW_FRAME', function (html) {
        if (!t.options.Botones.Limpiar) {
            $ob.find('#pw_fra_pac_Limpiar').hide(true)
        }
        if (!t.options.Botones.Nuevo) {
            $ob.find('#pw_fra_pac_Nuevo').hide(true)
        }
        if (!t.options.Botones.Detalle) {
            $ob.find('#pw_fra_pac_Detalle').hide(true)
        }
    })






    this._on(this.element, {
        "click": function (event) {

            if (event.toElement.type == "button" || event.toElement.type == "submit" || event.target.offsetParent.type == "button") {
                if (event.toElement.getAttribute("id") == "pw_fra_pac_Limpiar") {
                    this._trigger("Limpio")
                }
                if (event.toElement.getAttribute("id") == "pw_fra_pac_Nuevo") {
                    this._trigger("Nuevo")
                }
                if (event.toElement.getAttribute("id") == "pw_fra_pac_Buscar") {
                    this._trigger("Buscar")
                }
                if (event.toElement.getAttribute("id") == "pw_fra_pac_Detalle") {
                    this._trigger("Detalle")
                }
                return true
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });


},
```

})

This is the best way for do this?!!!!! Some ideas?!! I'm new in web programming.

Thanks